# Asynchronous translation with Google Translate API. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, google-translate

I always get tangled with asynchronous code, and I don't know where my mistake is.

This code reads product names from a database and puts them in the `untranslated` array. After that, the array is iterated over, every item is translated, and pushed in a new `translated` array.

The SQL part works fine, but unfortunately, the `translated` array is empty. I'm using the [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) and [translate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/translate) npm packages.

How can I make this work?

```
var untranslated = [];
var translated = [];

var query = `select name from products`

new sql.ConnectionPool(db).connect().then(pool => {
    return pool.request().query(query)
}).then(result => {

    for (var i = 0; i < result.recordset.length; i++) {
        var item = result.recordset[i];

        untranslated.push(item.name)
    }

    // I'm messing it up here somewhere.
    untranslated.map(item => {
        translate(item, { from: 'mk', to: 'en' }).then(result => {
            translated.push(result);
        })
    })

    console.log(translated); // Logs [];

}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    sql.close();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
Promise.all(untranslated.map(item => translate(item, { from: 'mk', to: 'en' })))
  .then(translated => console.log(translated));
```

In your original code you make calls to `translate`, which returns a Promise. A Promise is *eventually* fulfilled or reject. However, you create a lot of promises and then move on to immediately print `translated`. At this point, the Promises have not been fulfilled yet.

This is where [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) comes in. Instead of calling `then` for the individual promises, we pass all of them to `Promise.all`, which resolves if all promises have resolved and contains an array of all Promise results.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Thank you for the explanation. So if I were to put the translations back in the database, the `INSERT` statements need to be located inside `.then(translated => () => { // INSERTS })`, correct?

Comment: If you need to insert them all at once, yes. Otherwise you could still use individual callbacks.